# Processing data from query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, data-manipulation

I'm writing a 'get' function in a model class in codeigniter, but I need to process some of the data as it's returned, ideally without a whole bunch of overhead.

```
function get_answers($p)
{
    $result = $this->db->get_where('answer', array('a_upid_fk' => $p))->result();

    // foreach ($result->answer as $ans) {  
    //  $result->answers = explode( '|', $ans, -1 );
    // }

    return $result;
}
```

The results look like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'aid' => '742',
     'a_upid_fk' => '231',
     'answer' => '4555|||',
     'a_qid_fk' => '70',
     'created' => '2012-04-20 15:35:38',
     'last_modified' => '2012-04-20 15:36:11',
     'revision' => '1',
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'aid' => '743',
     'a_upid_fk' => '231',
     'answer' => NULL,
     'a_qid_fk' => '71',
     'created' => '2012-04-20 15:35:38',
     'last_modified' => '2012-04-20 15:35:38',
     'revision' => '1',
  )) ...
```

the problem is the answer is stored as a pipe delimited list of answers, but I want the function to return it as an exploded array instead. I'm not sure of the syntax and how to create and replace or append the array to the array of objects I've pasted above.

You can see some code I've been trying commented out.

Ideally instead of `'answer' => '4555|||',`
I would like to have

```
'answer' => array (
      0 => '4555', 
      1=> '', 
      2=> '')
```

I have no problem making the array using `explode` but I'm not sure how to modify the original codeigniter active-record result.

Answer (score 0):

Loop thru your sub-arrays:

```
$answer_array = explode('|', $answer);
foreach ($aswer_array as $instance)
{
  $result[] = $instance;
}
```

Define `__set_state())`, call it using - `$subarray = $result[0][$object->answer]`.

Comment: Hm never used __set_state or any magic methods. I'm not clear how I would apply that to what I have. There are an unlimited number of arrays to explode.. doesn't that need to be in the loop?

Comment: Sure, I just displayed a piece of code that might be confusing. All this should be inside of loop, just an example.

Comment: ah I don't really understand the role of `__set_state` there.. it's only in the original output bc of whatever codeigniter's doing